# I can not download Freya

Tags: release-freya

I gained Elementary OS and I can not download it, please help.
Try to download from Midori and OS is 0.2.1 Elementary Luna.

Comment: What is elementary OS moon ?

Comment: I assume the user is not a native English speaker and is trying to translate "Luna". elementary OS Luna has been replaced with elementary OS Freya, but they are unable to download it with their Luna installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can download Elementary OS Freya (the latest stable release) from [the main Elementary webpage](https://elementary.io/). They ask for a donation but you can also download and try it out for free but clicking `Custom`, entering $0, and clicking `Purchase`.

[image]

The easiest way to install Elementary is to use this downloaded ISO file to create a "bootable USB", these instructions show you how to create one depending on your current operating system:

[Create Elementary USB on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

[Create Elementary USB on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Simply reboot your machine with this USB drive plugged in and it should boot off the USB into Elementary OS. This distribution has Midori, the Pantheon desktop, terminal, and scratch text editor built in. You can install from this USB drive (including dual boot configuration options) and install additional packages from the Ubuntu Software Centre or try out the OS by running it directly from the USB.

Answer (score 0):

just go to the oficial web https://elementary.io/ and select the price you want to pay or simply type how much you think elementary OS cost in the custom box  and click in the download button.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if they meant "update" instead of "download" since they already have Luna installed. If that's the case, here is the link for instructions on how to download and [upgrade to the latest version of Elementary.](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-upgrade-from-Elementary-OS-Luna-to-Freya)